Why are my Chrome Extension permissions too broad?
Google developer portal says "You can significantly decrease review time by using more narrowly scoped permissions." I want this thing only to run when someone is using Microsoft Teams in Chrome, so I thought asking for permission only for that site would make sense.
I thought about using "activeTab" for the host, but doesn't that mean it would run on every site?
Here is my manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "IDFWDNFT",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Removes Teams requests to turn on desktop notifications.",
  "host_permissions":
  [
    "https://teams.microsoft.com/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts":
  [
    {
      "matches": ["https://teams.microsoft.com/*"],
      "js": ["IDFWDNFT.js"]
    }
  ]
}


Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

The posted manifest.json definitely doesn't have broad permissions, so either your actual one is different or it's a bug/mistake in the web store.

@woxxom It's definitely the exact manifest. Thanks for taking a look. :)
